# Check if request is from local host

Tags: asp-classic

How do I check if a request is from the local host with Classic ASP, like the bool property `HttpRequest.IsLocal` in ASP.NET?

Comment: try Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") this will provide you URL from this called the current URL and then you can find "localhost" in that and can know is this called from local or not.

Comment: I wouldn't be paying any attention to HTTP_REFERER in this scenario. It is spoofable and also not present unless someone has been redirected to your page from somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

How about using request.servervariables("remote_addr") and request.servervariables("local_addr") ?

Comment: `If (request.servervariables("remote_addr")=request.servervariables("local_addr")) Then` if true you are on localhost